# Is there a way to point always to latest version in a sharepoint folder?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, versioning

Might be a really easy question, but I am uploading always same file names in a sharepoint folder. 
Each file links is attached to a web page.

Problem is that each file uploaded is generating a new version FileXYZ (1.0 / 2.0 / 3.0...).
Is there a way to use as a link always the latest file uploaded to the folder?

https://mysite.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/Shared%20Documents/FileXYZ (latest)?

Is the line above enough to point always to latest file or do I need to append some param (&latest or ?)

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I have notice that removing the end hash is doing the trick, but would like some confirmation that this will always work:

https://mysite.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/Shared%20Documents/FileXYZ